# Octomap not available in MoveIt

Tags: moveit, octomap, ros-kinetic, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to represent my robots environment (available as a point cloud) as Octomap in MoveIt (ROS Kinetic) to make it available for collision checking. Therefore I mainly followed the Perception Pipeline Tutorial (http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/perception_pipeline/perception_pipeline_tutorial.html). Since I don't have an operating sensor I used a topic constantly publishing the point cloud. I created a pointcloud.yaml

```
 sensors:
  - sensor_plugin: occupancy_map_monitor/PointCloudOctomapUpdater
    point_cloud_topic: /fakesensor/pointcloud
    max_range: 5.0
    point_subsample: 1
    padding_offset: 0.1
    padding_scale: 1.0
    max_update_rate: 1.0
    filtered_cloud_topic: filtered_cloud
```

And added this to my launch file:

```
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot_registration)/config/pointcloud.yaml" />
    <param name="octomap_frame" type="string" value="world" />
    <param name="octomap_resolution" type="double" value="0.05" />
    <param name="max_range" type="double" value="15.0" />
```

Starting RViz I can observe the point cloud I am publishing but there is no Octomap available.
Any ideas what I am missing?

I also tried to use the octomap_server. My .launch file looked like this:

```
<launch>
        <node pkg="octomap_server" type="octomap_server_node" name="octomap_server">
                <param name="resolution" value="0.5" />
                
                <!--common frame id fixed map frame (set to 'map' if SLAM or localization running!) -->
                <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="world" />
                
                <!-- maximum range to integrate (speedup!) -->
                <param name="sensor_model/max_range" value="5.0" />
                    
                    <!-- data source to integrate (PointCloud2) -->
                    <remap from="cloud_in" to="/fakesensor/pointcloud"/>
        </node>
</launch>
```

I don't get any errors. In RViz I can add by topic the PointCloud2 /octomap_point_cloud_centers and the Marker Array /occupied_cells_vis_array. However in both cases there is nothing displayed in RViz. As far as I can see the topics are communicating fine. /octomap_point_cloud_centers Point Cloud in RViz is receiving messages. Echoing the /octomap_point_cloud_centers the data seems to be empty.
Thank you in advance for all ideas!

So far my only idea is having isues with the tf frames:
the pointcloud that i am sending has its own "sensor_frame" but i am also publishing the transformation between /sensor_frame and /world. Do I have to pay special attention to sth at this point. Do I have to use tf::TransformBroadcaster or tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster for the transformation to the sensor_frame?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324423/octomap-not-available-in-moveit/) by [Krebsileinchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34851/krebsileinchen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2019-05-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [S.Yildiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/36516/s.yildiz/) on 2019-06-03**:
Did you try to change the value from world to odom?

**Comment by [Krebsileinchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34851/krebsileinchen/) on 2019-06-03**:
I actually don't have an /odom frame

**Comment by [S.Yildiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/36516/s.yildiz/) on 2019-06-03**:
I can share you my experience: I had the similiar problem and when I changed the frame to odom it worked. So maybe you have to change the world frame to another frame

**Comment by [S.Yildiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/36516/s.yildiz/) on 2019-06-03**:
And you could check, if you get proper point cloud data

**Comment by [Krebsileinchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34851/krebsileinchen/) on 2019-06-03**:
I played around a bit with different frames but so far not successful. Did you work with the percepton pipeline or with the octomap server?
I can display the point cloud I am trying to process but I don't see any points when trying to display
/filtered_cloud or /octomap_point_cloud_centers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For everyone who's interested: In the end I found the solution and it was very simple. I just increased the sensor_model/max_range to 50.

Update 18.09.2019:
Actually my answer given before was not my main problem as I found out today. At that point I had just lost track of the different things I tried. The real error was that at first I added the parameter definitions and especially the load config definition just to my main launch file starting the visualization. Instead it needs to be added (at least the load config) to the repective sensor_manager.launch file of the robot.

---

Originally posted by [Krebsileinchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34851/krebsileinchen/) with karma: 51 on 2019-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-03**:
Was this because the environment in the static cloud you have extends beyond the 5 m range initially configured?

**Comment by [Krebsileinchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34851/krebsileinchen/) on 2019-06-05**:
the environment itself was not bigger but it was displaced from the world frame and therefore out of range